# What circuit is most efficient to boost 1.5V AA to 9V

Tags: power, batteries, dc, boost

While it’s impractical in real-world designs, is it possible to take a 1.5V AA battery and use some sort of circuit to boost to roughly 9V with around 10mA max output? There are so few chips that operate at below 3V and can do so efficiently. I’m assuming that this AA wouldn’t last as long as a more practical 9V battery, but this circuit is just for the heck of it..

Comment: A joule thief followed by a smoothing circuit could probably provide 10mA at 9V.

Comment: Asking what is best or if something is possible may not be very good questions. Best always depends on what you value most and we don't know much about it, so it is opinionated and most likely it is possble to do this, so could you be slightly more specfic what problem are you trying to solve instead?

Comment: If this did ever go into a design I would favor efficiency thus longer lasting battery. (edited title)

Comment: @zvolk4 This seems like you would be better off changing the consuming circuit. 9V seems an unusual value for the regulated voltage.

Comment: also citation needed on the 3V quote, 1.5V is a pretty common operating voltage.

Comment: The TL496 chip comes to mind, but it's capable of supplying much more current than you need and is over 20 years old. Here's a vid of circuit that can do 100mA - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWi0b5LQ6Jg

Comment: Pretty much every computer RAM chip nowadays runs off much less than 3V. DDR4 runs off 1.2V or 1.05V

Comment: yeah most battery-powered devices definitely contain exactly zero chips that need more than 3 V.

Comment: actually you want to boost 1V to 9V (or perhaps 6V) , else you're be throwing out AAs that contain a lot of unused energy,